# Rails routing: restricting requests on a route to only one format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following routes:

```
resources :tags do
  collection do
    get 'autocomplete', :constraints => { :format => 'js' }
  end
end
```

I would like this to only respond to JS requests (it's only for jQuery autocomplete), for a regular HTML request I think it should be a 404 response, or at least a redirect.

Instead, all requests are converted to JS format by the route, so an HTML request gets a json hash.

It isn't absolutely critical, but I would be much happier if I could cleanly restrict this route so that HTML requests to it were not allowed. How should that be handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `TagsController#autocomplete`, do the following:

```
respond_to do |format|
  # format.html { redirect_to some_path } # enable if you want to handle html requests as well
  format.js
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of this, but I'm trying to keep the controller as clean as possible here. Is there any way to handle this on the routing end, or with a built-in filter or something?

Comment: afaik, this is the proper way to handle requests for multiple formats

Comment: While I don't like how often I have to stick this in the controller, I think you're right that this is the only way to limit a response to only one format. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew if the controller only returns the js format, you might be able to put `respond_to :js` at the class level

Comment: @Andrew: I've created a gem which may help you with this kind of problem https://github.com/marcusg/force_format

Answer (score 1):

you could try this (not tested) :

```
get 'autocomplete', :constraints => { :format => 'js' }, :defaults => {:format => nil}
```

however,@prusswan's answer is the logical way to do it, and is more explicit. Keeping controllers thin is a good thing, but keeping them readable is better

Comment: So, this works in a way, but it just converts all requests to JS, which isn't really what I want. Thanks for the suggestion, though, this could be a helpful technique for other situations.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

`scope format: true, constraints: { format: 'html' } do
    get '/home' => 'home#index'
  end`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I feel the accepted answer is inaccurate. What you want to do is:

```
get 'autocomplete', constraints: lambda { |req| req.format == :js }
```

The accepted answer is doing:

```
get 'autocomplete', :constraints => { :format => 'js' }, :defaults => {:format => nil}
```

However If I want to restrict to a specific format, I'd expect that requesting the resource with a different format would return a 404, that is not the case unless you use a lambda. The reason why is explained in the Rails routing guide. To summarize, the key "format" is optional by default unless you use a lambda.

> For example, get 'foo', constraints: { format: 'json' } will match GET
> /foo because the format is optional by default. However, you can use a
> lambda like in get 'foo', constraints: lambda { |req| req.format ==
> :json } and the route will only match explicit JSON requests.

Source: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html